# How to find the text based on preceding text or classname using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm new to web scraping, and I've been using Selenium for this particular project. In this example, I'm crawling through the listings on a website and they are structured as follows...

**Listing 1:**

```
<html>
     <div class="div_class">
          <i class="first_i_class" style="i_style"> ::before </i>
          First Category: 
          <span class="span_class">5</span>
          <br>
          <i class="second_i_class" style="i_style"> ::before </i>
          Second Category: 
          <span class="span_class">3</span>
          <br>
     </div>
</html>
```

As you can see, the values for the first and second categories are similar, so finding all elements and then using a regex won't work here. I need to be able to get the text (5 and 3, in this example) based on the preceding text, in this case "First Category: " or "Second Category: ". Some listings, however, might skip certain categories and look like this...

**Listing 2:**

```
<html>
     <div class="div_class">
          <i class="third_i_class" style="i_style"> ::before </i>
          Third Category: 
          <span class="span_class">7</span>
          <br>
     </div>
</html>
```

Because the categories change between listings, I don't think I can use something like:

`cat_2_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/div/span[2][@class='span_class']")`

because the xpath will also change. Is there a way that I can find the text in a given span based on either

1. The preceding text (like "First Category: ") or
2. The preceding `<i>` class (like "first_i_class")?

Any help or clarifying questions are much appreciated!

Comment: One thought is that I could try to find all of the text associated with each <br> tag? I think that would include both the category and the value? But I'm not sure if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete @DebanjanB's answer, other options. As you requested :

> The preceding text (like "First Category: ") :

```
//span[preceding::text()[1][normalize-space()="First Category:"]]
```

Output : `<span class="span_class">5</span>`

> The preceding  class (like "first_i_class") :

```
//span[preceding-sibling::i[1][@class="first_i_class"]]
```

or

```
(//span[preceding-sibling::i[1][contains(@class,"i_class")]])[1]
```

Output : `<span class="span_class">5</span>`

If you want to get the second `span`, replace "first_i_class" with "second_i_class" in the first expression or change the last `[1]` for `[2]` in the second expression.

To get directly all the `span` elements, use :

```
//span[preceding-sibling::i[1][contains(@class,"i_class")]]
```

Output : `<span class="span_class">5</span>`
`<span class="span_class">3</span>`
`<span class="span_class">7</span>`

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts **`5`**, **`3`**, etc with respect to the preceding class `first_i_class`, `second_i_class` etc, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Printing *5*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='div_class']//i[@class='first_i_class']//following::span[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Printing *3*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='div_class']//i[@class='second_i_class']//following::span[1]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```